# Difficulty importing module in Python that was installed via homebrew on M1 Pro Mac

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, pythonpath, modulenotfounderror, libmagic

I'm currently developing a script called `script.py` that makes use of the `libmagic` package. I used `homebrew (3.5.9)` to install it via ZSH shell on an M1 Pro Mac.

As with any homebrew package installation, I used `brew install libmagic` and it installed successfully, but by the time I tried to import it to my program with `import magic`, the `ModuleNotFoundError` was thrown.

[image: Verified that libmagic was installed]

[image: Suspected that libmagic's path was not in PYTHONPATH]

At first, I thought the module was not found because it was installed as a third party module, so I added the path to `$PYTHONPATH` and I verified it via printing each entries with `sys.path`. But, I still get the same error.

[image: Persisting ModuleNotFoundError]

One assumption I made here is that the path I gave to `$PYTHONPATH` is where the `magic` module is located, but I think I have done something wrong here because the module search path clearly has the path I included so why is it still throwing the same error?

Clearly, the path listed in `$PYTHONPATH` was included as shown below, so why can't the module be found?
[image: Search path printed via sys.path]

I'm suspecting that I'm not using the right directory for my `$PYTHONPATH` and most tutorials out there uses an Intel chip which has a different file structure than the one in M1 Pro. The packages installed in the M1 Pro are stored under `/opt/homebrew/Cellar` and I might have missed some important steps.

Anybody who has experienced similar problems, please show me the way. Thank you.

Comment: You need to install the Python [bindings](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) aswell: `pip install python-magic`

Comment: Hi @MauriceMeyer, thank you for the comment! I used `pip3 install python-magic` instead of `pip` and the error was resolved. However, I'm quite confused with the term 'binding' and have looked it up on homebrew's [website](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python). Aren't homebrew and pip package managers and why do we need both of them?

Comment: The issue here is that, python-magic is just a binding to an application/library called `libmagic` (haven't checked in detail). `python-magic` is needed to communicate with that application/library. Use `pip` to install Python packages, `brew` to install shared libraries/applications.

Answer (score 3):

Install `libmagic` on Apple Silicon Macs based on M1 or M2 (or Mx):

**Step 1)** First, try to uninstall any other already-installed `libmagic` libraries and then install `python-magic-bin`:

```bash
$ pip uninstall python-magic
$ pip install python-magic-bin
```

**If it was successful, then you are all set!** If that fails, however, that means the wheel (binary) is not found for your Mac, then head to Step 2.

**Step 2)** Install `libmagic` via Homebrew:

```bash
$ brew install libmagic
```

**Step 3)** Copy the `magic` directory from [the repository](https://github.com/SHi-ON/libmagic-apple-silicon) to the directory where your Python environment libraries are located. Run `$ pip list -v` to be able to locate the path to your libraries directory. As an explanation on the origin of the `magic` directory, it has been derived from an Intel-based Mac with `python-magic` installed via pip.

**Step 4)** Copy `libmagic.dylib` from the `lib` directory in the libmagic that Homebrew has installed to the `magic/libmagic` directory in Step 3 to replace the `YOUR_libmagic.dylib`. Please note that you need to copy the original file, not the alias (symbolic link).
Run `$ brew list -v` to help you locate the path to the library installed by Homebrew. A typical path looks like `/usr/local/Cellar/libmagic/5.44/lib`.

If you have done the steps above, then you are going to be able to import libmagic:

```py
import magic
```

Comment: This is freaking magic!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the official version of libmagic module with these commands

```
> pip install python-magic
            or
> pip3 install python-magic ## if you have different versions of python installed
```

or if u dont have pip installed install it by using these commands

```
> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
> python3 get-pip.py
```

Comment: Hi @TucharDas, thank you for the guidance. I have resolved the problem with your suggestion, but do you happen to know why we need pip since homebrew was already a package manager?

Comment: U need both package managers because pip is specifically designed for python libraries but homebrew is designed for system wide applications